# Apply catalog price rule on all products of one category

Tags: magento-1.9, category, discount, catalog-price-rules, price-rules

i have different cataloge price rules for different products of different categories.

Now i want to add a new minus discount to a category with 60 products (-5%), which i implemented successfully. But only 1 product (that has already a discount) gets a new price. The other products arent affected and i dont know why.
I want a new catalog price rule that affect ALL products of one category and increase the price by e.g 5%, whether they have a discount or not.

Answer (score 0):

If you followed the customaziation for adding negative discount in this question https://magento.stackexchange.com/a/261752/76597 there should be correct price entries in the table `catalogrule_product_price` for the corresponding products.

```
-- change the values with those of your rule / prodcut you want to check and the actual date
select * from catalogrule_product_price where rule_date = '2019-02-15' and  customer_group_id = 0 and product_id = 44;
```

If you find that entry your rule is working.

There is only one more hint: In `Mage_CatalogRule_Model_Observer` there are two checks where the rule price is only applied, if it is below the regular price. Therefore you have to overwrite the two methods `processFrontFinalPrice($observer)` and `processAdminFinalPrice($observer)` and replace and bypass that check. For example like this:

```
if ($this->_rulePrices[$key]!==false) {
     // $finalPrice = min($product->getData('final_price'), $this->_rulePrices[$key]);
        $finalPrice = $this->_rulePrices[$key];
        $product->setFinalPrice($finalPrice);
    }
```

I hope that helps.

Comment: Thank you for your answer. I changed the code in "Mage_CatalogRule_Model_Observer" - now the new higher price shows up on every site (cart, detail site) exept the category page. There is the old price without the negative discount....