# Magento - Catalog Rule only on special price

Tags: magento-1.9

Good morning,

i changed the catalog rule - now i can insert negative discounts (e.g -5%) to increase the price of different products.
The actual problem is, that the price increases only on products that have a special price, but i want to apply the change (e.g -5%) to every product in a category.

How can i archive that?

Thank you
Chris

Comment: Did you check my answer here: https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/261956/apply-catalog-price-rule-on-all-products-of-one-category/262014#262014 This question looks like a duplicate to me. Please check the answer and give me a feedback on that, if it works for you